# How to install patched modules in fresh Drupal 10 Installation?

Tags: drupal, upgrade, patch

I have a fresh Drupal 10 Installation und would like to install some modules with more ore less simple patches. I tried it in different ways and get allways the same errors with composer require.

This are my steps:

1. **manual changed files** for exampe in superfish for this patch:
   https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2022-08-01/superfish-%233.patch and manually put the module in module/contrib folder. Than I tried composer require drupal/superfish:~1.4 with different versions and with and without parameter -W.
2. **I wrote patch in composer.json and tried composer install**. There comes the message nothing to install or update. I used also composer update --lock
3. **I downloaded last dev-Version and patch and tried with git apply**.

The result with composer require is more ore less the same error like this:

> Problem 1 - drupal/block_content_permissions[1.0.0, ..., 1.8.0]
> require drupal/core ^8 -> found drupal/core[8.0.0, ..., 8.9.20] but
> these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another
> require. - drupal/block_content_permissions[1.9.0, ..., 1.10.0]
> require drupal/core ^8 || ^9 -> found drupal/core[8.0.0, ..., 8.9.20,
> 9.0.0, ..., 9.5.0] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require. - Root composer.json requires
> drupal/block_content_permissions * -> satisfiable by
> drupal/block_content_permissions[1.0.0, ..., 1.10.0].
>
> You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version
> constraint, e.g. "composer require drupal/block_content_permissions:*"
> to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require
> drupal/block_content_permissions:^2.1" if you know which you need.

If I enable the patched modules manualy in backend, they work normaly. But they are not under composer controll.

How to do in the right way?

Answer (score 4):

Drupal.org has a documented process for allowing a [lenient composer install](https://www.drupal.org/composer/lenient).

For Drupal 10:

> Try the [Lenient Composer Plugin](https://github.com/mglaman/composer-drupal-lenient)
>
> The lenient composer plugin lets you specify an allowlist of packages
> where you are willing to break the version constraint, using a command
> like:
>
> ```
> composer config --merge --json extra.drupal-lenient.allowed-list '["drupal/token"]'
> ```
>
> Together with the [Composer Patches Plugin](https://github.com/cweagans/composer-patches), this allows you to install
> any Drupal extension, even if the version constraint hasn't been
> officially updated yet. Of course the code may still need to be
> patched for deprecations.

Comment: Sorry @rocketeerbkw i found your answer only now.
I get an error message 

"Warning from https://packages.drupal.org/lenient: The Drupal lenient endpoint has been deprecated and does not support Drupal 10. Use mglaman/composer-drupal-lenient. See https://www.drupal.org/composer/lenient for more information."

I dont understand what to do correctly.

Comment: You need to install `composer require mglaman/composer-drupal-lenient`

Answer (score 1):

To use Drupal lenient Patch.

-- First install `lenient patch` in composer

```bash
$ composer require mglaman/composer-drupal-lenient
```

Objective of lenient patch - is to make available the Drupal modules overcome the Drupal core version requirement.

But you need to add the (Drupal 10 ready) Drupal.org patch link in `composer.json`

Example : `userpoints` module do not have `drupal 10` release yet. So, to add `Drupal 10` compatible patch.

```bash
$ composer config --merge --json extra.drupal-lenient.allowed-list '["drupal/userpoints"]'
$ composer require 'drupal/userpoints:^2.0@beta'
```

-- Add working [latest #8](https://www.drupal.org/project/userpoints/issues/3314326#comment-14724954) patch in `composer.json`, only the patches part - or you can compare with your `composer.json` file

```json
{
  "require": {
      "mglaman/composer-drupal-lenient": "^1.0",
      "drupal/userpoints": "^2.0@beta"
  },
  "extra": {
      "patches": {
          "drupal/userpoints": {
              "deprecated drupal 10 readiness": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2022-10-09/userpoints-n3314326-8.patch"
          }
      },
      "drupal-lenient": {
          "allowed-list": ["drupal/userpoints"]
      }
  }
}
```

Now `composer update` will delete and re-patch the module. In the above `userpoints` module used, there are so many modules having `Drupal-9` but no `Drupal 10` release.

So, you can even add issue queue in `Drupal.org`, and put your own patch-file link in `composer.json` preceded by the `leninent` composer method to allow particular module.

For details on Lenient Patch

1. [Using Drupal's Lenient Composer Endpoint](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/using-drupals-lenient-composer-endpoint)
2. [Github mglaman/composer-drupal-lenient page](https://github.com/mglaman/composer-drupal-lenient)